Impossible to "Archive for publishing" in xamarin forms
I'm developing a xamarin.forms application through Visual Studio for Mac 2022.
I'm trying to "Archive for publishing" for android, but it seems impossible.
If, in android manifest, I set minSdkVersion = API level 28 and targetSdkVersion = API level 28, no issue, it creates archive.
But I can't upload this binary because I get error in Google play console (the error is "Your app currently targets API level 28 and must target at least API level 33 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance)
If, in android manifest, I set targetSdkVersion = API level 33, I get different error, for example "Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Net.Http" that could not be resolved", or some stupid warning like not used variable...
any idea how to solve?
I tried to change minSdkVersion (33 or lower) but I need, as targetSdkVersion, version 33
I expect to create package as it happens with targetSdkVersion lower than 33

Probably has to do with Xamarin being unsupported...
